# HTML Button Not Reappearing After Being Clicked

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

As you can see [here](https://dev.theobearman.com/buttons/) when you click a 'METAR' button one after the other, the previous button reappears when the next one is clicked.

However, when you click the 'Total Users Online on VATSIM' button, followed by one of the 'METAR' buttons, the 'Total Users Online on VATSIM' button does not reappear.

My code is located in [this Pastebin](http://pastebin.com/xvtV2xJE).

The JavaScript for the 'Total Users Online on VATSIM' button is as follows:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
var userButtons = $('.getUserButtons');
userButtons.click(function(){
var clickedButton = $(this);
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/online.php",
            dataType: 'html',
            success: function(data) {

                $('#outputDiv').hide('slow', function() {
                    $(this).remove();
                });

                userButtons.show('slow');

                var outputElement = $('<div id="outputDiv" style="color: white;">' + data + '</div>');
                outputElement.hide();
                outputElement.insertAfter(clickedButton);

                clickedButton.hide('slow', function() {
                    outputElement.show('slow');
                });
            },
            error: function(jqXHR) {
                alert(jqXHR.responseText);
            }
        });
    });
});
</script>
```

The code for the button itself is as follows:

```
<li><button style="height: 40px;" class="btn btn-primary getUserButtons hvr-float-shadow">Total Users Online on VATSIM</button></li>
```

Any assistance would be appreciated. I think I need to edit the code so that clicking one of the 'METAR' buttons then tells the 'Total Users Online on VATSIM' to reappear; I don't know how though.

Thanks!

Comment: It would be easier to create an example in your question using the editor or to use JSFiddle.

Comment: Agreed with TheDude, but I think you need a `data-location` attribute in your `getUserButtons` classes.

Comment: @MrLister The `data-location` attribute is specifically for the php file that gets the output of the 'METAR' buttons.

Comment: @MrLister I've removed that line to avoid confusion as it is irrelevant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally fixed the issue. Here it is:

```
script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {

    var metarButtons = $('.getMetarButtons');
    var userButtons = $('.getUserButtons');

    metarButtons.click(function(){
        var clickedButton = $(this);
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "metarData.php",
            data: { location: clickedButton.attr('data-location') },
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(data) {

                $('.metarOutput').hide('slow', function() {
                    $(this).remove();
                });

                $('#outputDiv').hide('slow', function() {
                    $(this).remove();
                });

                metarButtons.show('slow');
                userButtons.show('slow');

                var outputElement = $('<div id="outputDiv"' + data['location'] + ' style="color: white;" class="metarOutput">' + data['metar'] + '</div>');
                outputElement.hide();
                outputElement.insertAfter(clickedButton);

                clickedButton.hide('slow', function() {
                    outputElement.show('slow');
                });
            },
            error: function(jqXHR) {
                alert(jqXHR.responseText);
            }
        });
    });
});
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {

    var metarButtons = $('.getMetarButtons');
    var userButtons = $('.getUserButtons');

    userButtons.click(function(){
        var clickedButton = $(this);
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "online.php",
            dataType: 'html',
            success: function(data) {

               $('.metarOutput').hide('slow', function() {
                    $(this).remove();
                });

                $('#outputDiv').hide('slow', function() {
                    $(this).remove();
                });

                metarButtons.show('slow');
                userButtons.show('slow');

                var outputElement = $('<div id="outputDiv" style="color: white;">' + data + '</div>');
                outputElement.hide();
                outputElement.insertAfter(clickedButton);

                clickedButton.hide('slow', function() {
                    outputElement.show('slow');
                });
            },
            error: function(jqXHR) {
                alert(jqXHR.responseText);
            }
        });
    });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

add getMetarButtons class to Total Users Online on VATSIM as well

Comment: That doesn't work because getMetarButtons is calling /metarData.php as the url.